# Re-caulking vinyl windows exterior, what material do I remove, what needs to stay?

Tags: windows, sealing, caulking, vinyl

The addition to our home has very low quality vinyl windows, and board and baton siding. There are some gaps starting to appear. Looking at the photo, arrow #1 points to ~3/8" of a caulk or rubber gasket-like material, that has been painted over. In some areas it is so uniform I might believe it's preformed gasket, not hand applied caulk. But in other areas it looks sloppy like caulk.

Arrow #2 points to a rigid material, can't tell if it's plastic or aluminum, but its' joints are looking rough.

So where I see gaps between material 1 and 2, do I need to completely remove 1, then just caulk with 100% silicone? Or is it possible to just fill in the gap and leave material 1 where it is, since most of it still appears to be sealing.

[image]